# Using Linq to look for gap in dates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a single queryable that is ordered by id and then by date in descending order (most recent will appear first), tracking when the item (id) was online. If a gap is detected (more than 1 day) I want to filter out all of the dates that come prior to the gap, as to only get the most recent range of online days.

Currently I am looping through with for loops, however the data set is very large so I would like to improve performance using linq.

Are there any ways to compare the records by id, then date, and remove elements of that id after a gap is detected ( current.date - next.date != 1)?

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022/01/01 |
| 1 | 2021/12/31 |
| 1 | 2021/12/25 |
| 2 | 2021/12/20 |
| 2 | 2021/12/19 |
| 2 | 2021/12/18 |
| 2 | 2021/12/15 |

would return:

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022/01/01 |
| 1 | 2021/12/31 |
| 2 | 2021/12/20 |
| 2 | 2021/12/19 |
| 2 | 2021/12/18 |

Comment: Not that I know of. But perhaps you can change how you query your data. If you are querying by date range, then you know how many unique dates there are in that date range. So you can group records by `Id` and count unique `Date`. You can filter out `Id` with less number of unique `Date` as there are within the date range you are using in your query.

Comment: > "Currently I am looping through with for loops, however the data set is very large so I would like to improve performance using linq."



That's misguided, LINQ doesn't help with performance, if anything it can decrease performance due to extra allocations for all the iterators.

Comment: Do you want to do that on the server side?

Comment: Please use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = queryable
            .GroupBy(entry => entry.Id)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(entryGroup => entryGroup
                .OrderByDescending(entry => entry.Date)
                .Aggregate((EntryGroup: new List<Entry>(), GapDetected: false), (accumulated, current) =>
                {
                    if (accumulated.GapDetected) return accumulated;
                    var previous = accumulated.EntryGroup.LastOrDefault();
                    if (previous == null || (previous.Date - current.Date).Days < 2) accumulated.EntryGroup.Add(current);
                    else accumulated.GapDetected = true;
                    return accumulated;
                }))
            .SelectMany(entryGroup => entryGroup.EntryGroup)
            .ToList();
```

Note that only the GroupBy portion of the code is actually executed as an SQL query and the rest of the query is done locally since it can not be translated to SQL. I couldn't come up with a solution where the entire query could be translated to SQL but I wanted to show how this can be done with LinQ.